# Changing WordPress website urls from localhost\ to something else

Tags: wordpress

I developed a WordPress site and then hosted it on godaddy.com but problem is that I have previous urls set for pages that are localhost/aboutus etc, I know that I need to change them but totally clueless about how should I do so.

Comment: This is off-topic for [SO]. Your best bet is to research over on https://serverfault.com/ and the wider internet.

Comment: Agreed this is off-topic for SO, but I'd suggest sending them to wordpress.stackexchange.com.  That being said, changing the domain / hostname of a WP installation is extremely well documented in a number of places and OP just needs to do some basic research to answer their question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can do this from settings.

#### Option 1

**Dashboard->Settings->Permalinks.** 
(https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)
You can write a custom permalink structure there.

#### Option 2

If you want to rewrite the "localhost" just setup the field here:
"Site Address (URL)" and "WordPress Address (URL).

The same can be found here:
**Dashboard->Settings**

Comment: I am confused that what are that urls that need to be written instaed of localhost urls because my domain name urls  are not working

Comment: In the case, it should be the IP of your server, I believe.

The easiest way is to just enable the domain and type it in the field. It will save you a bunch of time.

Comment: no you are not understanding it , landing page works fine but others doesnot work.

Comment: Hey Harmaen,

If your domain is videos.dev, you have to input it in the field in the settings mentioned above. (https://codex.wordpress.org/images/a/ad/permalink-settings.png)
Also, make sure to add the default .htaccess file(https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess), as it can also cause the issue that you are explaining.

Comment: Thank you !I just had to change permalink option to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hey Harmaen, please feel free to upvote the answer, if you think it might help others.